# How to make an horizontal array like this {1\2\3\.....\n} for an excel formula?

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I normally use:

```
transpose(row(indirect("1:"&finalrange)))
```

Using only:

```
row(indirect("1:"&finalrange))
```

will do a vertical array of consecutive numbers.

So I want to know if there is a shorter way to do this.

Comment: You can use `COLUMN` instead of `ROW`.  But I don't think you can create a horizontal array of more than 16,384 items using this method. I don't like using `INDIRECT` as it is a volatile function, but for small worksheets, probably not an issue.

Comment: I think you're missing some key information here. How does `row(indirect("1:"&finalrange))` *"do a vertical array of consecutive numbers"*? (It does nothing for me.)  What do you this *for*, and why does it matter if you find a slightly "shorter way" than a 30-character formula that you only have to type once? ...and if it does matter, why not use just `=A1+1`, etc?

Comment: This is about arrays and using Ctrl+shift+ enter